# Ordering permutations based probabilities

Tags: python, algorithm

As a simple example: I'm trying to brute force a 4 digit passcode. This passcode can consist of the digits `0-9`.

If I didn't know anything about the passcode, I could try brute forcing in a random order, or sequentially, for example `0000`, `0001`, `0010`, `0011`, etc, and it should take me on average half the size of the set of possible passcodes.

Now, if I know for a fact that the number 9 is way likely to appear at least once than the number 0 (from a large sample set of passcodes), is it possible to order my search to (on average) result in a faster cracking time?

Specifically, given a set of probabilities of at least one of the corresponding digit appearing in the code:

```
[0: 0.1, 1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.6, 6: 0.7, 7: 0.8, 8: 0.9, 9: 0.95]
```

How could I write an iterator or generator (in Python or C#) to brute force this passcode in the most optimal way possible? For example in this case it should be testing codes with at least one `8` more often than codes with at least one `1`.

Perhaps, when generating each passcode to test, there should be a 95% chance of using the number 9 at least once, 90% chance of the number 8, etc, something like that?

Will this actually result in a speedup? Is there an algorithm for this I should look into?

Better yet, for actual brute-force password cracking, is this done in any specific order (as people are more likely to use english words for passwords, vowels will be more common than the capital Z)?

Comment: If it were me, I'd generate all the passwords (10,000 is a pretty small number), assign each of them a probability according to whatever criteria you want, and then sort them in reverse order by probability.

Comment: well if you know that 9 is present at list one position then from earlier 10000 cases your chances are now 1000 so you need to calculate those 1000 cases not 10000 cases so 9000 cases become useless and more speedup the things

Comment: So to assign a "score", I'd need something like the binomial probability of at least one occurance of that digit, for each digit, multipled together?

Comment: To expand a bit more, `sort(all_keys, reverse=True, key=probability_for_key)`.  Then write the function probability_for_key and have it generate its probabilities in whatever way you want.  Seems you want to put the digits into a set, and then multiply the probabilities of the digits in that set.

Comment: https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mschucha/netsec/readings/cfgPass.pdf this seems to be similar

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possible ways to approach this:

## 1. Offline generation:

Generate the probabilities for each combination offline, and reverse-sort it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['code'] = [str(i).zfill(0) for i in range(10000)]

## You can update this probability-map to any numbers you want:
prob_map = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95]

df['prob'] = df['code'].apply(lambda x: prob_map[x[0]]*prob_map[x[1]]*prob_map[x[2]]*prob_map[x[3]])

df = df.sort_values(by='prob'], ascending=False)
```

The dataframe will now contain the list of codes in the order you should be trying them.

## 2. Online trial:

Generate 4-random 1-digit numbers with the given probability-map.

Also maintain a set of already `tried` codes.

```
# We first need to adjust the probabilities such that sum(all_probs) = 1:

prob_map = [x/sum(prob_map) for x in prob_map]

dig = [get_digit_with_prob(prob_map) for _ in range(4)]
code = ''.join([str(x) for x in dig])

## get_digit_with_prob() implementation is quite trivial, simply a if-else loop
```

## 3. Analytical solution:

If you observe closely, the probability-map for digits mention that larger the digit, larger is its probability.

We can simply extend this argument, and say further than its true not just for 1-digit number but also for 4-digit number.

So, simply doing a alphabetic-reverse-sort on the rangeo of [0, 9999] should suffice:

```
codes_to_try_in_order = [str(x) for x in range(10000)].sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Solution (3) makes a huge assumption that doesn't seem to correspond to the original problem. Solution (2) suggest using "a if-else loop" to implement what appears to be an exact duplicate of [the already-existing function `random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). Solution (1) parachutes a long formula to calculate some probability without explaining what it means.

Comment: Finally, solutions (1) and (2) both use probabilities in a dubious way; the OP stated `prob_map[i]` was the probability that the digicode contained at least one occurrence of digit `i`. But I'm not sure these probabilities are consistent; *i.e.*, it's not clear that there exists a probability distribution on the 10000 digicodes that would result in those individual probabilities on the digits.